# Entity Framework multi Level join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

for my beginner question.

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.0.2 and I'm trying to figure out why my collection of IpAddresses is null.

I have three Models Device, Nic and IpAddressPool which stand in a 1+N Relationship:
1 Device -> n Nics -> n IpAddresses.

I'm trying to get this constellation into my view of my MVC Project.

My Method to get the Data in my IndexController looks as following:

```
private List<Device> GetDevicesAsync()
    {
        var devices = _context.Devices
                      .Include(nics => nics.Nics)
                      .OrderBy(o => o.DeviceMetadata.DeviceType.SortNumber)
                      .ThenBy(o => o.DeviceMetadata.DeviceName)
                      .ToList();
        return devices;
    }
```

In my Devices-Class there's a navigation property of type ICollection<'Nic'> and in my Nic-Class there's an navigation property of type ICollection<'IpAddressPool'>

In the view I iterate over the model devices and per device I iterate over the Devices.Nics Everything is fine but when I iterate in my nics to get all the IpAddresses bound to the nic it's allways null:
Note that I've inserted the Collection of IpAddressPools into a variable for testing, which then is null.

```
var devices = Model.Devices;
    foreach (var d in devices)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@d.id</td>
            <td>@d.DeviceMetadata.DeviceName</td>
            <td>@d.DeviceMetadata.DeviceType.TypeName</td>
            <td>@d.DeviceMetadata.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName</td>
            <td>
                @{ 
                    foreach (var nic in d.Nics)
                    {
                        <b>@nic.Brand</b><br />
                        var nics = nic.IpAddressPools;
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@d.id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@d.id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@d.id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Why is the Collection of IpAddressPools not field It's the same approach like I did on the Nic?

In my Databases IpAddressPools the Nicid is filled with the id of a nic and even though I think that there should not be raised a null exception in the view. Instead it should simply display no IpAddress.

I assume that my mistake is in the LINQ-Statement because I reference to the Nics but not to the IpAddressesPool because I've not figured out how to get it.
Because nics.Nics returns a Collection of nics I'm not able to point to the IpAddressesPool.

When I'm right, how do i manage to get the IpAddresses from the pool which are related to it's nic?

Many thanks for your help.
monsee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I am following all your explanations, but if you want to ask EF (Core) to include another collection in collections you can use `ThenInclude` it like this  :

```
  _context.Devices
     .Include(device => device.Nics) // I renamed the parameter for clarity heer
     .ThenInclude(nic => nic.IpAddressPools) // supposing the navigation property is called IpAddressPools, of course.
```

Alos, please note that maybe Intellisense is complaining at the beginning and doesn't let you autocomplete the 'ThenInclude', but once you wrote it correctly, it will detect the syntax correctly (and it will compile anyway).

Comment: And here's the problem, because within the Nic-Class the navigation property is of Type ICollection<'IpAddressPool'> you can't get it via nic => nic.IpAddressPools When I would declare the property of type IpAddressPool there will be created an IpAddressPoolid-column within my Nic-table at the next migration and I'll loose the 1+n relationship.

Comment: "within  Nic-Class the navigation property is of Type ICollection<'IpAddressPool'> you can't get it via nic => nic.IpAddressPools". Well, yes you can. That's the point of the navigation property and the ThenInclude.

Comment: @monsee This Intellisense issue now is even mentioned in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation: *"**Note** Current versions of Visual Studio offer incorrect code completion options..."*

Comment: Wow, tha's realy poor. But the ThenInclude-Extension method really works in that way. There's just no Intellisense. Thanks to all who guided me into the right direction. Thumbs up.